# Websockify base64: 'False'

Tags: websocket

When I'm starting websockify with python2.7 on my server no warnings appear, everything is ok.
But when the first connection comes in there are problems with base64 I think:

```
 1: <ip>: Plain non-SSL (ws://) WebSocket connection
 1: <ip>: Version hybi-13, base64: 'False'
 1: connecting to: <myserver.com>:64749
```

On the client side I get an error in safari but it also tells me that the connection is made and I'm able to send and receive messages:

```
WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused ws://localhost:17523
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error about connecting to ws://localhost:17523 is harmless. In order to test whether the WebSocket API supports binary data it is necessary to actually instantiate a WebSocket object, however, WebSocket objects must be instantiated with an actual destination so websock.js uses a localhost port to test the connection. The browser complains that the connection fails but websock.js is able to use that object to do its test.

The `base64: False` indicates that the client and server have negotiated to use raw binary data and don't need to use base64 encoded strings to encode the data. Base64 encoding is necessary in older browsers (or with web-socket-js emulator) that support WebSockets but not binary data.

Since you are successfully sending and receiving data, I assume this question is just verifying that the messages you are seeing aren't major problems correct?